# How to maintain 2d Lists in Java ?

Tags: java

I know how to maintain a `1D` Integer List, which can be done by -

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a.add(100);
a.add(101);
```

What I want to do is something like, extending `a` to `2D`

```
a[0].add(100); // will push 100 back to a[0].
a[1].add(101);
```

Comment: Do you mean `List<List<Integer>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a list of lists, eg:

```
List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
a.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
a.get(0).add(5);
a.get(0).get(0);
```

or can have an array of lists but since arrays of parametric types are not directly allowed you are forced to use raw types:

```
List[] a = new List[10];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  a[i] = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go for List  which contains `List`, like

```
List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
```

or

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<String>> listOlists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();

singleList.add("hello");
singleList.add("world");

listOlists.add(singleList);

List<String> anotherList = new ArrayList<String>();

anotherList.add("This is another list");
listOlists.add(anotherList);
```